# How to view cd contents

Tags: 12.04, cd

I know its a stupid question but I'm new to ubuntu. isn't a window supposed to pop up and say cd inserted or something as in windows. I looked up in the file browser but there is nothing related to cd drive. is the problem with my drive ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1puAI.jpg) is how it looks when you mount cd in ubuntu 12.04. Did you try putting different cd/dvd in your drive?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The CD should appear under **Devices** in any Nautilus (file browser) window. If it doesn't, then there are a few possibilities:

- It could be an audio CD, rather than a data CD. Then you can listen to it or rip it in Rhythmbox, Sound Juicer, or whatever other application you prefer.
- The CD could have no readable filesystems. This could be due to damage to the CD, or a problem with your CD drive, or a problem with your Ubuntu system. You can troubleshoot this sort of problem by inserting the CD, waiting about 10 seconds, opening a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and running the command `dmesg | tail -20`. That shows the last 20 lines of system messages, which may document any problems and/or reveal if the CD is being detected at all.
- There could be a problem with Nautilus, though this is not very common. You can run `mount` in a Terminal window to view all mounted devices, and see if the CD is mounted.
- It could be a blank CD-R (or CD-RW). Typically a blank disc will pop up a message asking you what you want to do, but this behavior can be disabled. If you know it's a blank disc and your intention is to write something to it, then you can burn files (or an `.iso` image) to it with CD burning software available in Ubuntu, such as Brasero.

You may want to add more information to your question (including the results of running the `dmesg` and `mount` commands above). That might make possible an answer more specific to your situation.